# Troubles linking to a static library on windows with CMake

Tags: c++, c, cmake, static-libraries, libraries

LS,

I'm trying to build a static and dynamic library that can be used to link with both dynamically and static. I would like the library to run on as many platforms as possible no matter the compiler used. In order to build the library and a few test programs I'm using CMake to build the library eeg on Linux and on windows using g++ and MSVC++ respectively.

On Linux both the dynamic and static libraries seem to work as I suspected, on windows the .dll seems to link perfectly and my test programs run. However, a program using the static library complains about linking errors. I really miss the point what I'm doing wrong, It could be something in my CMakeLists.txt, but also in the Setup of my library.
Below I've made a minimal program that uses my library that demonstrates the issues I'm experiencing. The library consists of two C++ files, an C API that exports the code in the C++ files, a C++ program that uses the C API and finally a CMakeList.txt that can build all programs but the program that uses the static library. This all to yields a wonderfull "Hello, World!".

I know I show a lot of code, but at least it is a minimal project that demonstrates my problems with linking to the static library. I hope someone is kind enough to take a look at this project and explain me what I'm doing wrong.

Kind regards,

hetepeperfan

The C++ file PriCpp.cpp

```
#include "PriCpp.h"

using namespace std;
string PriMessageBuilder::message() const {
    return "Hello, World!";
}
```

The header PriCpp.h

```
#ifndef PRICPP_H
#define PRICPP_H

#include <string>

class PriMessageBuilder{
public:
    std::string message() const;
};

#endif
```

The C API is:
mycapi.h

```
#ifndef MYCAPI_H
#define MYCAPI_H
#include "builder_export.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {} message_builder;

BUILDER_EXPORT message_builder* message_builder_new();
BUILDER_EXPORT void             message_builder_destroy(
                                        message_builder* builder
                                        );
BUILDER_EXPORT char*            message_builder_message(
                                        message_builder* builder
                                        );
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

mycapi.cpp is:

```
#include "mycapi.h"
#include "PriCpp.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

message_builder* message_builder_new() {
    PriMessageBuilder* ret = NULL;
    try {
        ret = new PriMessageBuilder();
    } catch (...) {
    }
    return reinterpret_cast<message_builder*>(ret);
}

void message_builder_destroy(message_builder* builder)
{
    PriMessageBuilder* b = reinterpret_cast<PriMessageBuilder*>(builder);
    delete b;
}

char* message_builder_message(message_builder* builder)
{
    PriMessageBuilder* b = reinterpret_cast<PriMessageBuilder*>(builder);
    return strdup(b->message().c_str());
}
```

The program that I use in combination with the library above.
program.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "mycapi.h"

using namespace std;

class MessageBuilder {
public:
    MessageBuilder() : m_builder(message_builder_new()) {
    }
    ~MessageBuilder() {
        message_builder_destroy(m_builder);
    }
    string MessageBuilder::message() {
        char* msg = message_builder_message(m_builder);
        string m(msg);
        free (msg);
        return m;
    }
private:
    message_builder* m_builder;
};

int main(int, char**) {
    MessageBuilder m;
    cout << m.message() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and finally CMakeLists.txt to build a makefile or a visual studio solution

```
#setting up project
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project(libbuilder CXX) 
include (GenerateExportHeader)

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

#creating library
add_library(builder SHARED PriCpp.cpp PriCpp.h mycapi.cpp mycapi.h)
add_library(builder-static STATIC PriCpp.cpp PriCpp.h mycapi.cpp mycapi.h)

generate_export_header(builder)

set_target_properties(builder PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -DBUILD_BUILDER_SHARED)
set_target_properties(builder-static PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -DBUILDER_STATIC_DEFINE)

#creating programs
add_executable(program program.cpp)
add_executable(program-static program.cpp)

target_link_libraries(program builder)
target_link_libraries(program-static builder-static)
```

If I build the solution I get these linker errors:

```
1>program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__message_builder_new referenced in function "public: __thiscall MessageBuilder::MessageBuilder(void)" (??0MessageBuilder@@QAE@XZ)
1>program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__message_builder_destroy referenced in function "public: __thiscall MessageBuilder::~MessageBuilder(void)" (??1MessageBuilder@@QAE@XZ)
1>program.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__message_builder_message referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall MessageBuilder::message(void)" (?message@MessageBuilder@@QAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
1>K:\duijn119\programming\cmake\staticsharedlib\build\Debug\program-static.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

The CMake generated include header is:

```
#ifndef BUILDER_EXPORT_H
#define BUILDER_EXPORT_H

#ifdef BUILDER_STATIC_DEFINE
#  define BUILDER_EXPORT
#  define BUILDER_NO_EXPORT
#else
#  ifndef BUILDER_EXPORT
#    ifdef builder_EXPORTS
        /* We are building this library */
#      define BUILDER_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#    else
        /* We are using this library */
#      define BUILDER_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#    endif
#  endif

#  ifndef BUILDER_NO_EXPORT
#    define BUILDER_NO_EXPORT 
#  endif
#endif

#ifndef BUILDER_DEPRECATED
#  define BUILDER_DEPRECATED __declspec(deprecated)
#endif

#ifndef BUILDER_DEPRECATED_EXPORT
#  define BUILDER_DEPRECATED_EXPORT BUILDER_EXPORT BUILDER_DEPRECATED
#endif

#ifndef BUILDER_DEPRECATED_NO_EXPORT
#  define BUILDER_DEPRECATED_NO_EXPORT BUILDER_NO_EXPORT BUILDER_DEPRECATED
#endif

#define DEFINE_NO_DEPRECATED 0
#if DEFINE_NO_DEPRECATED
# define BUILDER_NO_DEPRECATED
#endif

#endif
```

Comment: Not really sure, but do you really need `extern "C"` in the header since you have C++ implementation?

Comment: @dmi Yes I'm quite sure I need extern "C". I want to use the c calling conventions, so that there is no namemangling. This makes it easier to call functions from the library from a C program. The C API also hides the classes from the standard C++ library across the dll boundary. That maintains ABI stability between different C/C++ compilers.

Comment: Does problem remain if you remove all non-static libraries and executables? If so, please, post `CMakeLists.txt` without them.

Comment: Show the `BUILDER_EXPORT` macro

Comment: @ixSci The BUILDER_EXPORT is generated by CMake in `#include "builder_export.h"` but I'll include the header.

Comment: What if you change `set_target_properties(builder-static PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -DBUILDER_STATIC_DEFINE)` to `set_target_properties(builder-static PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS -DBUILDER_STATIC_DEFINE)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `set_target_properties(program-static PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS -DBUILDER_STATIC_DEFINE)` after `add_executable(program-static program.cpp)`. Currently your static library gets build right but the application gets the library header with wrong `declspec`(well, there should be no `declspec` at all and you have one)

Also, it seems more appropriate to use the following notion:

```
set_target_properties(program-static PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS BUILDER_STATIC_DEFINE)
```

`COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` instead of `COMPILE_FLAGS`

Comment: Excellent awnser. Guess I'm still a CMake Noob. The define -DBUILDER_STATIC_DEFINE definately is making it to the documentation of my library when linking to the static library. I don't think I would have figured this one out myself, although it is so logical when someone points to it.